# Como posso usar o Gesture com o GridView?

Tags: flutter, dart, gridview

Preciso de ajuda para quando o usuário clicar na imagem, abrir a página correspondente.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:health/page-health/doador.dart';
import 'package:health/page-health/imc.dart';

class GridDasboard extends StatelessWidget {
   Items item1=  new Items( title: "IMC - Peso e Altura", img: "assets/images/balanca.png" );
  Items item2 = new Items(title: "Doador ", img: "assets/images/doador.png");

   var links = [
     IMCPage(),
     DOAPage(),

   ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Items> myList = [item1, item2];
    var color = 0xffD3D3D3;

    return Flexible(
      child: GridView.count(
          childAspectRatio: 1.0,
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8, right: 8),
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          crossAxisSpacing: 18,
          mainAxisSpacing: 18,
          children: myList.map((data) {
            return Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Color(color), borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Image.asset(
                    data.img,
                    width: 42,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 14,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    data.title,
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6,
                  ),

                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () async {
                      await Items();
                    },
                  ),
                ],

              ),
            );

          }).toList()),

    );

  }
}

class Items {
  String title;
  String img;
  Items({this.title, this.img});
}
```

Comment: De uma olhada nesses dois links, devem lhe atender: [Navegando entre telas no Flutter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UKkAUkrhwH4); [Navegação entre telas (Rotas Nomeadas)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9olJ-lTSM8E).

Comment: obrigada, mas meu objetivo é a partir de uma imagem no gridview ir para a page

Comment: Certo... Então EDITE sua pergunta e explique seu problema, de mais detalhes. Pois vi que você está utilizando ali o `GestureDetector` que deixa o _Widget_ clicável, sendo assim, basta apenas aplicar o que foi ensinado nos vídeos que indiquei.

Comment: Se lhe ajudar, a estrutura do item deve ser `return GestureDetector > Container > Column`, ou seja, você precisa deixar o `GestureDetector` por primeiro, assim cada item da grid será clicável.

Answer (score 0):

Vc pode cobrir o Container, dps do retorno com o Widget Gesture Detector. Q ai o container todo vai virar uma espécie de objeto clicavel. E vc acrescenta o onTap e nele coloca um navigator para a pagina q vc quer exibir